# std::bad_alloc when declaring new int[n]

Tags: c++, linux, g++, bad-alloc

The program is supposed to take an array from user-input and split it into two arrays for negative and non-negative values respectively.

The program works up to and including

```
count(userList, n, numPos, numNeg);
```

The error throws when I declare

```
int *negList = new int[numNeg];
int *posList = new int[numPos];
```

I thought that changing it to

```
int *negList;
negList = new int[numNeg];
int *posList;
posList = new int[numPos];
```

would fix the problem, but it does not. The previous declaration of

```
int *userList;
userList = new int[n];
```

does not throw any error.

This happens both in Codeblocks on windows as well as on Linux with g++.

The whole code is below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//count positive and negative elements in list
void count(const int* arr/*list*/, int numElements/*num elements in array*/, int& numPos/*num positive elements*/, int& numNeg/*num negative elements*/);

int main()
{
  //declare variables
  int n;                  //number of elements
  int userInput;          //place holder for list values
  int numPos; int numNeg; //num positive and negative elements

  //prompt user for number of elements
  cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
  cin >> n;

  //declare array
  int *userList;
  userList = new int[n];

  //prompt user for list and read in
  cout << "Enter list: " << endl;
  cin >> userInput;
  for(int i(0); i < n; i++){
    cin >> userInput;
  }

  //count positive and negative elements
  count(userList, n, numPos, numNeg);

  //declare arrays for negative and positive elements respectively
  int *negList = new int[numNeg];
  int *posList = new int[numPos];

  // ...

  //free memory
  delete [] userList;
  delete [] negList;
  delete [] posList;

  return 0;
}

void count(const int* arr, int numElements, int& numPos, int& numNeg)
{
  for(int i(0); i < numElements; i++){
    if(arr[i] < 0){
      numNeg++;
    }
    else{
      numPos++;
    }
  }
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How big is the `n` you are using? It might be impossible to allocate such a large amount of contiguous memory

Comment: I don't see any initialization of `numNeg` before use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `numNeg` and `numPos` to `0`.

Comment: I feel really dumb right now! That was so fast that I'm not even allowed to accept it for 7 more minutes

Answer (score 3):

```
int numPos; int numNeg;
```

Since you have not assigned anything to these values (or initialized them) they are default initialized to an indeterminate value [read more here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). What's likely happening is they come out very large and are too big for `new` to allocate space.

Set them both to 0 at first:

```
int numPos = 0;
int numNeg = 0;
```

Though it would be more correct for `count` to set them to 0, since the post-condition of the function is that they are equal to the number of positives and negatives seen, rather than having been incremented that many times

```
void count(const int* arr, int numElements, int& numPos, int& numNeg {
    numPos = numNeg = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Another error is that you never populate your `userList` but instead keep reading into the same `userInput` variable, your initial for loop should be

```
//prompt user for list and read in
cout << "Enter list: " << endl;
for(int i(0); i < n; i++){
  cin >> userList[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned above, initializing variables to zero and passing them by reference (its address, not its value) will solve the issues you encountered.

I compiled and debugged it to a working version.
The debugger is your friend when you want to solve these kind of issues ; and use watches to see the content of the variables and arrays to check it.
Here the corrected code. Have fun with it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//count positive and negative elements in list
void count( const int* arr          /*list*/, 
        int numElements         /*num elements in array*/, 
        int& numPos             /*num positive elements*/, 
        int& numNeg             /*num negative elements*/);

//split list into list of positive elements and list of negative elements
void split( const int* original     /*original list*/, 
        const int numOrig       /*size of original list*/, 
        int* negList            /*negative list*/, 
        int& numNeg             /*size of negative list*/, 
        int* posList            /*positive list*/, 
        int& numPos             /*size of positive list*/);

//prints array
void print_array(const int* arr, const int arrSize);

int main()
{ 
    //declare variables
    int n;                  //number of elements
    int userInput;          //place holder for list values

//prompt user for number of elements
    cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    cin >> n;

    //declare array
    int* userList = NULL;
    userList = new int[n];

    //prompt user for list and read in
    cout << "Enter list: " << endl;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> userInput;
        userList[i] = userInput;    
    }

    //count positive and negative elements
    count(userList, n, numPos, numNeg);

    //declare arrays for negative and positive elements respectively
    int* negList = new int[numNeg];
    int* posList = new int[numPos];

    //split array into positive and negative arrays
    split(userList, n, negList, numNeg, posList, numPos);

    //print arrays
    cout << "Negative elements: " << endl;
    print_array(negList, numNeg);
    cout << "Non-negative elements: " << endl;
    print_array(posList, numPos);

    //free memory
    delete[] userList;
    delete[] negList;
    delete[] posList;

    cin >> userInput;  // added to show result in console window (can be removed)

    return 0;
}

void count(const int* arr, int numElements, int& numPos, int& numNeg)
{
    numPos=0;           //num positive and negative elements
    numNeg=0 ; 

    for (int i(0); i < numElements; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            numNeg++;
        }
        else {
            numPos++;
        }
    }
}

void split(const int* original, const int numOrig, int* negList,  int& numNeg, int* posList,  int& numPos)
{
    numPos = 0;           //num positive and negative elements, reset to zero
    numNeg = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < numOrig; i++) {
        if (original[i] < 0) {
            negList[numNeg] = original[i];
            numNeg++;
        }
        else {
            posList[numPos] = original[i];
            numPos++;
        }
    }
}

void print_array(const int* arr, const int arrSize)
{
    for (int i=0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        cout << " " << arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: This isn't right. Your functions should set their arguments to 0 before they start counting

Comment: @Ryan, I just used the code of the requester and corrected it to show which things needs to be changed (as explained), it is not wrong, but I agree that setting variables to zero in both count and split function is better. I changed it accordingly in the code above. Thanks.